# How to calculate percent change of each month, from median of previous months

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have data that looks like this:

```
Group  YearMonth  PageViews  Users
A        202001      100        10
A        202002      120        9
B        202002      150        12
A        202003       90        10
B        202003      120        15
C        202001      130        10
```

I want to find out the percentage difference of each new month from the median of the previous month's usage, under each group For example,

1. For first row ( each group might have different first date for example, group A has 202001 and groupb b has 202002 as first observation) it will be NA
2. For **group A** the median of the previous month
   will be only 202001, so the percentage difference for pageviews for
   202002 will be 20% and user would be -10% as compared to 202001
3. Similarly for 202003, the median of previous months would be 110 ( 100+120 by 2 = 110)
   median of 202001 and 202002 combined, so pageview median , and user
   is 9.5, so the percentage difference for 202003 will be -19% for
   pageviews and +5% for users and so on.

How can I find this using python? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) method to get the median of all values before and `shift` the result to align it with the following YearMonth, do this per Group using `groupby`.

```py
# get expanding median of the two columns and shift
median_prev = (
    df.sort_values('YearMonth')
      .groupby('Group')
      [['PageViews','Users']]
      .apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
)
print(median_prev.sort_index())
#    PageViews  Users
# 0        NaN    NaN
# 1      100.0   10.0
# 2        NaN    NaN
# 3      110.0    9.5
# 4      150.0   12.0
# 5        NaN    NaN
```

Then do the math of percentage difference as you want. I assume you want:

```py
# create the two columns, no need of sort_index, 
# will do it automatically index and column alignment
df[[f'%change_{col}' for col in ['PageViews','Users']]] = \
    ((df[['PageViews','Users']]/median_prev-1)*100).round(1)

print(df)
   Group  YearMonth  PageViews  Users  %change_PageViews  %change_Users
0     A     202001        100     10                NaN            NaN
1     A     202002        120      9               20.0          -10.0
2     B     202002        150     12                NaN            NaN
3     A     202003         90     10              -18.2            5.3
4     B     202003        120     15              -20.0           25.0
5     C     202001        130     10                NaN            NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

by controlling the group column, you may need to shift the pageviews.

1. convert the data to descending, so the last one will be the first one

```py
df=df.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

2. shift the views by controlling the group

```py
df["PageViews_1"] = df.groupby("Group")['PageViews'].apply(lambda x: (x.shift(1)))
```

so that, at each row, you will have the next months records.
in the end, you can simply calculate the mean as

```py
 df['mean']=(df["PageViews_1"]+df['PageViews'])/2
```

for the median, given that you will all the shifted values next to Group A, you can calculate for each row.

```py
 df['median']=df.median(axis=1)
```

Comment: `apply(lambda x: (x.shift(1)))` is replaceable with `shift()`.